# updating a value in sink table -azure data factory

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to move data from Mariadb to Azure SQL database lets assume that the table in the Azure SQL contains the following data :

| id | state | insert time | updated value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-01-01 14:30:00 | yes |
| 2 | 100 | 2022-01-01 14:30:00 | yes |
| 10 | 200 | 2022-01-01 14:30:00 | yes |

Lets assume I retrieved data from the marinade and it returned the following results :

| id | state | insert time | updated value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 2022-01-01 15:30:00 | yes |
| 2 | 200 | 2022-01-01 15:30:00 | yes |
| 12 | 100 | 2022-01-01 15:30:00 | yes |

What I want to do is to check if the query results from the Maria returns ids that are exists in the azure SQL if it exists it updates the value of "updated value" column in the azure SQL to No then insert the query results of the Mariadb so the table should look like this :

| id | state | insert time | updated value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-01-01 14:30:00 | NO |
| 2 | 100 | 2022-01-01 14:30:00 | NO |
| 10 | 200 | 2022-01-01 14:30:00 | yes |
| 1 | 300 | 2022-01-01 15:30:00 | yes |
| 2 | 200 | 2022-01-01 15:30:00 | yes |
| 12 | 100 | 2022-01-01 15:30:00 | yes |

Most of the things I found on the internet are performing upset but I want to keep the old data in order to have insights on the states per a given time . So how can I implement such a thing

Answer (score 0):

After you insert the new data you should be able to update the existing records with something like this (not tested) assuming you have the new 'insert time'.

```
update yourTable 
set [updated value] = 'NO' 
where id in (select id from yourTable where [insert time] = @NewInsertTIme)
```

where &NewInsertTime is the new 'insert time' (2022-01-01 15:30:00 in your example).  You can use the Script Activity to run the code or put it in a stored procedure and use the Stored Procedure Activity to call it.